# SwiftUI Widget empty when built onto device or simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

Playing with SwiftUI and WidgetKit recently and faced a nasty problem. My widget seems to be working in the SwiftUI Canvas but it is completely empty when built onto a simulator or device.

**Images:**

**In SwiftUI canvas:**

https://github.com/beanut/images/blob/main/Screenshot%202020-12-19%20at%204.00.57%20PM.png?raw=true

**When built onto the device:**

https://github.com/beanut/images/blob/main/Screenshot%202020-12-19%20at%204.01.13%20PM.png?raw=true

**My code:**

```
'''
 import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date())
    }
    
    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date())
        completion(entry)
    }
    
    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries = [SimpleEntry]()
        let currentDate = Date()
        let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: currentDate)
        let nextMidnight = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: midnight)!
        //To refresh timeline every min
        for offset in 0 ..< 60 * 24 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: offset, to: midnight)!
            entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: entryDate))
        }
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(nextMidnight))
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
}

struct WidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var body: some View {
            HStack() {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(DateManager().getDayOfWeekInString(date: entry.date)!)
                            .font(Font(UIFont(name: "HoeflerText-Italic", size: 44)!))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                            .opacity(1)
                        Text("\(DateManager().getDayAsString(date: entry.date)) \(DateManager().monthAsString(date: entry.date))")
                            .font(Font(UIFont(name: "Copperplate", size: 26)!))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                            .opacity(1)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                Spacer()
                VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: -20) {
                    Text(DateManager().getHour(date: entry.date))
                        .font(Font(UIFont(name: "Copperplate-Bold", size: 86)!))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .opacity(1)
                    Text(DateManager().getMinuteWithTwoDigits(date: entry.date))
                        .font(Font(UIFont(name: "Copperplate-Bold", size: 86)!))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .opacity(1)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                .padding(.trailing, 15)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "moon")), alignment: .center)
    }
}

@main
struct Widget: SwiftUI.Widget {
    let kind: String = "Widget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            WidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("TestWidget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}

struct Widget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date()))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemMedium))
    }
}

'''
```

****Update**
I noticed that the widget does show if I remove a VStack. But it doesn't show if I add the code back.
**Removing the VStack:**

```
struct WidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var body: some View {
            HStack() {
//                VStack {
//                    Spacer()
//                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
//                        Text(DateManager().getDayOfWeekInString(date: entry.date)!)
//                            .font(Font(UIFont(name: "HoeflerText-Italic", size: 44)!))
//                            .foregroundColor(.white)
//                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
//                            .opacity(1)
//                        Text("\(DateManager().getDayAsString(date: entry.date)) \(DateManager().monthAsString(date: entry.date))")
//                            .font(Font(UIFont(name: "Copperplate", size: 26)!))
//                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
//                            .opacity(1)
//                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
//                    }
//                }
//                .padding(.leading, 20)
//                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                Spacer()
                VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: -20) {
                    Text(DateManager().getHour(date: entry.date))
                        .font(Font(UIFont(name: "Copperplate-Bold", size: 86)!))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .opacity(1)
                    Text(DateManager().getMinuteWithTwoDigits(date: entry.date))
                        .font(Font(UIFont(name: "Copperplate-Bold", size: 86)!))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .opacity(1)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                .padding(.trailing, 15)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "moon")), alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

**It does show the UI elements:**
https://github.com/beanut/images/blob/main/IMG_002DAA718D1C-1.jpeg?raw=true

Please help me with it and thanks in advance :)!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm encountering something very similar.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon this question trying to find a fix for this same issue for myself, and have since found a solution.

I don't believe the `VStack` was the problem here, but rather force unwrapping one or more of the values for the UI elements inside it, as in this line for example:

```
Text(DateManager().getDayOfWeekInString(date: entry.date)!)
```

Force unwrapping a `nil` value was what was stopping drawing widget's UI for all sizes for me. Try unwrapping the values the safe way or provide a fallback by nil coalescing.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you call `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines` in the `getTimeline` function:

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    ...
    for offset in 0 ..< 60 * 24 {
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines() // <- this is wrong
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: offset, to: midnight)!
        entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: entryDate))
    }
    
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(nextMidnight))
    completion(timeline)
}
```

The whole point of `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines` is to force refresh the timeline and effectively call the `getTimeline` function again.

It's a bad idea to call it from inside `getTimeline`, especially in the loop.

The code in previews may be working because the `getTimeline` function is called once only and all repetitive calls are ignored.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't solve my main problem, but my Mac no longer heats up like crazy now. :) It seems that the widget works when a VStack is removed and stops working when I add the stack back. I've updated my question :)